# option "class_prefix" unknown metasyntactic

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocol-buffers

I am using [metasyntactic](https://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers) to convert my protobuf to objective C. I am trying to use the extension for adding class prefix. My code looks like

```
import "google/protobuf/objectivec-descriptor.proto";

option (google.protobuf.objectivec_file_options).class_prefix = "TS";

message Test {
  optional string s1 = 1;
  optional string s2 = 2;
}
```

But when I try to compile it, I get the error:

```
Option "(google.protobuf.objectivec_file_options)" unknown
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work. Turns out I can't use "package" and the extensions together. I'll update this if I find a way to use them together.

EDIT: As Kenton mentioned in the comments, the reason was that I was using "google" in my package name which confused the compiler. you can fix it by adding a leading ., i.e. (.google.protobuf.objectivec_file_options)

Comment: The only reason I can think of why `package` would interfere is if your package name contains `google` as a component. In that case, when you specify `google.protobuf.objectivec_file_options`, the compiler will think the first `google` refers to your package named `google`, not the global one. Is that the case? If so, you can fix it by adding a leading `.`, i.e. `(.google.protobuf.objectivec_file_options)`.

Comment: @KentonVarda this was indeed the case. I remove google from the package and everything worked smoothly, adding "." also works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import "google/protobuf/objectivec-descriptor.proto";
option (.google.protobuf.objectivec_file_options).class_prefix = "AC";
```

with this command to specify where to search import paths:

```
protoc --plugin=/usr/local/bin/protoc-gen-objc --proto_path=.:ProtocolBuffers/src/compiler/ my.proto --objc_out="./"
```

I am using this version of protobuf: http://protobuf.axo.io/#objc